# No logro usar ALERT en JAVAFX

Tags: javafx, alert

Como podrán notar, soy muy novato en el tema de JAVAFX, por lo que estuve practicando para aprender creando un login que se conecta a base de datos, si el usuario y contraseña coinciden muestra un mensaje que dice: "ACCESO CONCEDIDO" y si no muestra otro mensaje, todo bien hasta ahí, ya que estuve usando JOptionPane para mostrar los mensajes y me di cuenta que no quedaba con el estilo de javaFX, por lo que investigue y encontré los ALERT, decidí aplicarlos a mi función del login, y simplemente no me funciona, me aparece el típico (cannot find symbol):
[image: ERROR]

Incluso incluí en el proyecto el JAR de controlsfx y simplemente no logro hacer que me funcione, si alguien con mas experiencia podría ayudarme se lo agradecería, adjunto mi función:

```
 import java.awt.Window;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.sql.Statement;
 import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


 public class log {
Conector cone = new Conector();

public void entrar(String username,String pass) throws SQLException{

    if (username.length()>0 && pass.length()>0){
    try{
        Connection con = cone.connect();
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario = '" +username+"'AND contra ='" +pass+"';" ;
        ResultSet r = s.executeQuery(sql);
        boolean found = false;
        int user_id = 0;
        while (r.next()){found=true; user_id= r.getInt("id");}
        if(found){
         Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION); //Aquí el error
        alert.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        alert.setTitle("COMPLETO");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("ACCESO CONCEDIDO");
        alert.showAndWait();

        }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario y contraseña incorrectos");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Algo salío mal");
    }finally{
    try{
    cone.closeCon();
    }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error al cerrar la conexión");
    }
    }
    }
}


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás importando la librería javafx.scene.control.Alert

Además estás importando clases de awt y swing lo cual es incorrecto y puede dar incompatibilidades, solamente deberías usar JavaFX y sus librerías ya que está pensado para que puedas servirte de ellas sin echar en falta nada de las anteriores, ten en cuenta que awt y swing se encuentran deprecados.

Soy estudiante de programación, llevo un año estudiando y ya no se enseña swing ni awt, ahora se enseña JavaFX así que haces bien en dar el salto.